# React and Express not working?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I'm fairly new to Node.js, react, and Express. I'm trying to make a basic application and it seems like I can't initialize express.

When I do `npm start` I get this in the terminal

> ./node_modules/express/lib/view.js
>       81:13-25 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

My package.json looks like

```
{
  "name": "matchplay",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.17"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

and my index.js looks like

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import {AppTitle, LoginForm} from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

const express = require('express')
const app = express();


const element = (<div>  
                    <AppTitle/>
                    <LoginForm/>
                </div>);
ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

When I go to my localhost:3000 the following error is given to me;

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
>   ./node_modules/express/lib/request.js
>   node_modules/express/lib/request.js:31

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Have you done installing node modules into your project? If not please do 'npm install' and add all the dependencies first. All the best!!!

Comment: @ganka I just ran that command, seems to be the same issue.

Comment: Are you really using express in your project? If not please remove it from the dependencies in package.json

Comment: @ganka I'm trying to, but I haven't been able to continue since it keeps giving errors. I want to set up routing and use client-sessions

Comment: Similar problems are being suppressed by webpack-node-externals module. Please refer here https://github.com/liady/webpack-node-externals

Comment: @ganka Thanks for the link, I'll look into it.

Comment: You should not mix Express & React in 1 file together. They should be 2 different projects. In production, Express should serve built files from React and during development you should proxy React API calls to Express port.

Answer (score 2):

You should separate the Express server and the React client into two different folders and implement each as their own standalone app--as in each having their own  `package.json`, `/node_modules`, etc.

You are building two distinct applications, the front-end React App which is connected to the back-end Express Server. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning on serving your react app with express your code won't do, you are giving your client express which will basically allow them to host their own server?

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import {AppTitle, LoginForm} from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

const express = require('express') //<--- Here
const app = express(); //<--- and here
//These should not be here 


const element = (<div>  
                    <AppTitle/>
                    <LoginForm/>
                </div>);
ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

If you want to serve your react build using an express server it should be a separate project, or at-least a meta project where the react app builds into your express app's public directory.